# Find all possible combinations column value in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Could you please help me to solve this Below Query:

I have below table of data.

| EmpNo | Name | City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | US |
| 2 | Miranda | US |
| 3 | Pete | US |
| 4 | Jack | US |
| 5 | Kathy | UK |
| 6 | Tanni | UK |
| 7 | Sally | UAE |

I want output as like below:

| City | Name1 | Name2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | John | Miranda |
| US | John | Pete |
| US | John | Jack |
| US | Miranda | Pete |
| US | Miranda | Jack |
| US | Pete | Jack |
| UK | Kathy | Tanni |

PLSQL we can write block to get this output. But is it possible to get output using SQL code alone?

Comment: Are you looking for cartesian join? `select a.City, a.Name as Name1, b.Name as Name2 from MyTable a, MyTable b`

Comment: US, UK, UAE are cities?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko It is not cartesian product. Basically i want find out all possible combination Names by location wise. Also, It should not have any duplicate entry as well as reverse order entry. i.e : John -- Miranda combination is appeared in result then  Miranda -- John combination should not come.

Comment: @mathguy Yes. Location name.

Comment: "City" is much more specific than "location name". If you wanted "location", then that would be a much better column name than "city" (for values like US, UK, UAE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
  input_table (empno, name, city) as (
    select 1, 'John'   , 'US'  from dual union all
    select 2, 'Miranda', 'US'  from dual union all
    select 3, 'Pete'   , 'US'  from dual union all
    select 4, 'Jack'   , 'US'  from dual union all
    select 5, 'Kathy'  , 'UK'  from dual union all
    select 6, 'Tanni'  , 'UK'  from dual union all
    select 7, 'Sally'  , 'UAE' from dual
  )
-- end of sample data (for testing only, not part of the query)
-- remove WITH clause and use your actual table name below
select t1.city, t1.name as name1, t2.name as name2
from   input_table t1 inner join input_table t2
                      on t1.city = t2.city and t1.empno < t2.empno
order  by t1.empno, t2.empno   -- if needed
;

CITY  NAME1    NAME2  
----- -------- --------
US    John     Miranda
US    John     Pete   
US    John     Jack   
US    Miranda  Pete   
US    Miranda  Jack   
US    Pete     Jack   
UK    Kathy    Tanni
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a self join.

```
SQL> with temp (empno, name, city) as
  2    (select 1, 'John'   , 'US'  from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Miranda', 'US'  from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Pete'   , 'US'  from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Jack'   , 'US'  from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Kathy'  , 'UK'  from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'Tanni'  , 'UK'  from dual union all
  8     select 7, 'Sally'  , 'UAE' from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.city, a.name, b.name
 11  from temp a join temp b on a.city = b.city and a.name < b.name
 12  order by a.city, a.name;

CIT NAME    NAME
--- ------- -------
UK  Kathy   Tanni
US  Jack    Miranda
US  Jack    John
US  Jack    Pete
US  John    Pete
US  John    Miranda
US  Miranda Pete

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: It seems that your output is different from the one requested. Difference is in the second join condition.

Comment: Right, @mathguy, thank you. Should've been EMPNO instead of NAME. Though, those still are *combinations* and the general idea (of how to write such a query) still stands.